# ¿Como obtener los elementos del mismo nombre de un XML?

Tags: java, xml

Necesito obtener el attributo `url` de todos los elementos `<media:content/>` de un XML similar a este.

```
<rss version='2.0' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'>
    <channel>
        <item>
            <media:group>
                <media:content url='https://valor'/>
            </media:group>
        </item>
        <item>
            <media:group>
                <media:content url='https://valor'/>
            </media:group>
        </item>    
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Este es un método que intente, pero `contents.getLength()` retorna cero.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

Document doc = builder.parse(inputStream);
NodeList contents = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/", "content");
```

He intentado usar XPath... otra vez `contents.getLength()` retorna cero.

```
XPathFactory factory2 = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = factory2.newXPath();
// XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//content"); 
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//*[name()='content']");
NodeList contents = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Nunca obtengo los nodos necesarios, ¿alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Solo como consulta, ¿es necesario utilizar XPath o te parece bien utilizar una librería para parsear tu XML en una estructura como `Map<String, Object>` y buscar los datos en el map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para trabajar con los métodos `..NS`, cuando creas el DOM debes invocar al método `factory.setNamespaceAware(true);`

Comment: Muchas gracias Martin!

Comment: Para los que no saben martin contesto en el sitio en ingles, aquí: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36364063/2573335

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el valor de un atributo (en este caso url), teniendo un `.rss` de la forma:

```
<rss version='2.0' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'>
    <channel>
        <item>
            <media:group>
                <media:content url='https://www.stackoverflow.com'/>
            </media:group>
        </item>
        <item>
            <media:group>
                <media:content url='https://www.cnn.com'/>
            </media:group>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Se puede acceder a los  elementos obteniendo la lista de nodos y accediendo a sus valores :

```
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
    ...
    ...

      InputStream inputStream =  url.openStream();
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(inputStream);

        NodeList contents = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

            for (int i = 0; i < contents.getLength(); ++i)
            {
                Element elemA = (Element) contents.item(i);
                NodeList valueListB = elemA.getElementsByTagName("media:group");
                for (int j = 0; j < valueListB.getLength(); ++j) {
                    Element elemB = (Element) valueListB.item(j);
                    NodeList valueListC = elemB.getElementsByTagName("media:content");
                    for (int k = 0; k < valueListC.getLength(); ++k)
                    {
                        Element elemC = (Element) valueListC.item(k);
                       System.out.println("url: " + elemC.getAttribute("url"));
                    }
                }
            }
```

O se puede ir directamente a el elemento, en este caso "`media:content`" y obtener el valor de su atributo "`url`":

```
 try {
    URL   url = new URL(feedUrl);
    InputStream inputStream =  url.openStream();
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(inputStream);

        NodeList contents = doc.getElementsByTagName("media:content");
        for (int i = 0; i < contents.getLength(); ++i) {
            Element elemA = (Element) contents.item(i);
            System.out.println("url: " + elemA.getAttribute("url"));
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }catch (SAXException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

se obtendría el valor:

```
url: https://www.stackoverflow.com
url: https://www.cnn.com
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por responder! pero no funciona, ya habia probado algo parecido y tampoco funcionaba, no toma los elementos si los pides así elemA.getElementsByTagName("media:group"), el prefijo no va ahí, ademas el prefijo puede cambiar de un XML a otro.

Comment: Claro, uso getElementByTagNameNS pues content esta en un namespace. Y lo siento, pero no funciona.

Comment: ademas no es necesario navegar el dom de esa manera, pues getElementByTagName trae todos los elementos del documento, si impotar el nivel donde se encuentran, el truco esta en establecer setNamespaceAware(true), fijate en la respuesta de martin.

Comment: Eso lo se pero se supone este sitio es para dar opciones en fin. Entonces esto no funciona y no puede obtener el atributo url?

Comment: no con este método.

Answer (score -2):

XML:

0OK30-1-0000013-66271741VisaGoldBs50007000-200011/01/201511/01/2020ASCACamacho30-1-0000013-6111122222VisaGold$us40002000200011/03/201411/01/2019ASCAEl Tejar

JAVA:
Lees XML:
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = null;
        String messageError = null;
        Integer codResp = -1;
        String msjResp = "";
        try {
            db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlresponse));
            try {
                Document document = db.parse(is);
                NodeList codigoRespuesta = document
                        .getElementsByTagName("CodigoRespuesta");
                NodeList mensajeRespuesta = document
                        .getElementsByTagName("MensajeRespuesta");

```
            for (int i = 0; i < codigoRespuesta.getLength(); i++) {
                String codRespuesta = codigoRespuesta.item(i)
                        .getTextContent();
                codResp = Integer.parseInt(codRespuesta);
                msjResp = mensajeRespuesta.item(i).getTextContent();
            }
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
                logger.logDebug(messageError);
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
                logger.logDebug(messageError);
            return null;
        }
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
        // handle ParserConfigurationException
        e1.printStackTrace();
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
            logger.logDebug(messageError);
        return null;
    }
```

Sacas los datos:
try {
            db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlresponse));
            try {
                Document document = db.parse(is);

```
            // NodeList listDatos =
            // doc.getElementsByTagName("DatosTarjeta");
            // for (int i = 0; i < listDatos.getLength(); i++) {
            //
            // NodeList hijos = listDatos.item(i).getChildNodes();
            // for (int j = 0; j < hijos.getLength(); j++) {
            // logger.logDebug("Datos " + i + " : "
            // + hijos.item(j).getNodeName() + ": "
            // + hijos.item(j).getTextContent());
            // }
            //
            // }

            NodeList list = document.getElementsByTagName("DatosTarjeta");
            for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {

                NodeList elements = list.item(i).getChildNodes();

                logger.logDebug("Datos " + i + " : "
                        + list.item(i).getTextContent());
```

//TODO Aqui iteras en donde quieras que salga
}
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
                    logger.logDebug(messageError);
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
                    logger.logDebug(messageError);
                return null;
            }
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
                logger.logDebug(messageError);
            return null;
        }

Espero te sirva slds...

Comment: Porfavor edita tu respuesta de forma legible y explica lo que hace este código, así ayudarás más.